# how does google redirect a keypress event (no matter where) to its search text box?

Tags: javascript

make any search in google and you end up with the search text box and various other HTML elements (for the various matches).

I noticed that, no matter which HTML element has the focus, if you type a letter/number it gets picked up by the search text box.

Can somebody explain to me how google achieves that ?

I'd like to do something similar on my site.

p.s.
I was thinking to listen to key events from document but I am not sure if that is a good idea...

Comment: in that case please learn autocomplete..

Comment: @SohilDesai This has nothing to do with autocomplete. This is to do with redirecting key events to a text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something [like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/iX0LYzpC5lsfukN06pr0?p=preview).

The main ideea is to capture keyboard events closer to the root, window would be fine. Once you catched up one, you should focus your search input by adding the correct character typed before focusing. On input focus, don't forget to unbind the window keyup handler and bind it again on input blur. Some startup code to help you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var windowKeyupHandler = function(e) {
      var code = e.which || e.keycode;

      $('#typer').focus().val( $('#typer').val() + ' ' +  String.fromCharCode(code).toLowerCase());
           $(window).off('keyup.window');
      };

      $(window).on('keyup.window', windowKeyupHandler);

      $('#typer').on('blur', function(e) {
          $(window).on('keyup.window', windowKeyupHandler);
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is listening to key down on window and channeling it to the input.

Other way would be to capture each key down (that its target is not the input, you can see it in the event object), and set focus to the input, then appending the key. This way only the first key down would need to be "caught", the other will be automatically typed in the input.

Comment: Thanks, those are good ideas. Yet, i am after on how google does it ? do you happen to be able to work it out ?

Comment: Also if "One way is listening to key down on window and channeling it to the input." wouldn't I receive than two key down events ???

Comment: As far as I went through the code of their search page & event binding - they listen to keypress, keydown and keyup on document. Also, by channeling I meant appending the correct key to the input, not dispatching another event.

Comment: How do you know that they listen to document ? could not find that

Comment: @Zo72 right click anywhere on the page (using Google Chrome) -> Inspect element, while on elements, look on the right panel for "Event Listeners" tab... Et voilà!